# Angular - How show the current lenght of my cart items using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am doing a SPA using Angular 9. I would like a component that shows the CURRENT length from my cart items and this way automatically without refresh the page shows the lenght from my cart items (it will be used on a ecommerce).

The property on my template doesn't shows the current length after I have modified the length of my cart items.

If I refresh the page, then it shows the current length.

#### my.ts

```
public num_item:number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.NumItemsCart().pipe(take(1)).subscribe( result => 
          {this.num_item = result})  
}

NumItemsCart():Observable<number>{
  let cadena_items = '';
  let array_temp = [];
  let num_items=0;
  
  cadena_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

  array_temp= cadena_items.split(',')
    
  num_items= array_temp.length -1

  return of(num_items)
}
```

#### my template

```
<div *ngIf="(num_item) > 0">{{num_item}}</div>
```

Please, can someone show me the right way to do this and tell me why my method doesn´t works?

Answer (score 0):

This below block of code should move to cart change event, `ngOnInit` fires one-time during component initialization only.

```
this.NumItemsCart().pipe(take(1)).subscribe( result => 
            {this.num_item = result})
```

Comment: if I move this code out ngOnInit i get this message error from this code :
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Answer (score 0):

u can use the async pipe and the optional chain

```
<div *ngIf="(NumItemsCart|async)?.length > 0">{{(NumItemsCart|async)?.length}</div>
```

another way is change the `take(1)` to `takeUntil(destroy)`
and add class field at top `private destroy = new Subject()`, then in ngOnDestroy you can call

```
this.destroy.next();
this.destroy.complete();
```