# Angular - Show the current length value from a shop cart items(ecommerce) Rxjs on my template

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

im try do a counter for the items number of my shopcart. This counter I will show in my home page using Angular 9.

A function return the current number of items from my shopcart, and my template shows through a property the value of my function. Using Observables i thought the property show the current value of items from my shopcart without reload the page, but this dont happen like that. What did I forget to do before?

code .ts

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


constructor() { 

      this.NumItemsCart().subscribe(
      value =>  {this.num_item = value},
      error => console.log('was an issue here', error),
      ()=> console.info('Obs completed')
    )
  }

  NumItemsCart():Observable<number>{
    let string_items = '';
    let array_temp = [];
    let num_items=0;
    
    string_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

    array_temp= string_items.split(',')
    
    num_items= array_temp.length -1

    return of(num_items)
  }
```

code template

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <div *ngIf="(num_item) > 0">{{num_item}}</div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: You need to watch for changes in localStorage, As of now your code will be executed only once as you are not observing changes on localStorage, Have a look at this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - How show the current lenght of my cart items using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876820/angular-how-show-the-current-lenght-of-my-cart-items-using-rxjs)

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu The solutions given would work only once it ain't gonna watch for subsequent changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed creating an observable, but you are not making it to do the polling (checking your `localStorage` periodically).

You could do the following:

```
import {
  interval
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  map
} from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor() {

  const storage$ = interval(1000).pipe( // This will try to update every second
    map(() => {
      let string_items = '';
      let array_temp = [];
      let num_items = 0;

      string_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

      array_temp = string_items.split(',')

      num_items = array_temp.length - 1
      return num_items;
    })
  )
  storage$.subscribe(
    value => {
      this.num_item = value
    },
    error => console.log('was an issue here', error),
    () => console.info('Obs completed')
  )
}
```

There are other points you can improve in the code, but this should already unblock you.

Comment: Polling every second would be a bad idea in terms of performance , Better to use reactive wrapper around localStorage API or use event listener + the power of RXJS  to watch for changes.

Comment: Indeed. As I said, there are other points to improve the code. I would ask myself if using the localStorage as communication channel is really the way to go here.
If the localStorage is also updated inside the same angular application, there better ways to sync

Comment: @Vikas Furthermore, the npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage you have indicated only watch for changes using the library itself (which comes back to my comment that using the localStorage as message channel is not the way to go)